# Passing installer variables from Installation type screen to condition expression

Tags: install4j

I have added Installation Type screen to my install4j installer. In accrodance to selected installation type certain files are downloaded and unzipped. These actions are grouped into four groups and reside under "Installation"
To control this execution flow I use Condition expression on each group depending on selected type of installation

Here is the code:

```
if ((String)context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId") == "424")
    return true;
return false;
```

The problem is that it always returns false (not executed) even though I select Installation type.

Does anyone know why this happens? Maybe the

```
(String)context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId")
```

is not a String? Maybe it is an array? How do I write the condition properly?

Thanks!

---

Solutuon found!

I've found two workarounds for this problem

1. Use numeric values for installationTypeId and convert it to integer:

`if (Integer.parseInt(context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId").toString()) == 424) 
    return true; 
return false;`

1. Use equals() method inside if statement. It allows to use custom IDs.

`if (((String)context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId")).equals("424"))
   return true;
return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare strings with the equality operator, you have to use `equals`. The equality operator checks if both sides refer to the same object, which is generally not the case for dynamically created strings.

I would recommend to set the condition expression to

```
context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId").equals("424")
```

You don't need the if statement and the returns, the expression evaluates to a boolean.